# Fail to change HDMI display resolution on imx6

Tags: linux, qt

I am working on embedded product that runs on Embedded Linux & Qt Framework developed to run on i.Mx6 custom board that we built. We have LVDS display interface which is set at **1366x768** resolution.

`/ # cat /sys/class/graphics/fb0/mode U:1380x768p-59`

Now I am trying to interface the display on HDMI and am noticing that the resolution on HDMI monitor is not getting set properly it shows **1280x1024**.

`/ # cat /sys/class/graphics/fb0/mode V:1280x1024p-60`

I have tried to interrupt the boot process and tried to force the resolution by running the below step and proceed to boot

`U-Boot > set hdmi_video video=mxcfb0:dev=hdmi,1366x768M@60,if=RGB24 fbmem=10M,28M vmalloc=400M`

I noticed that the resolution was not being set again. I confirmed that by running below commands:

`/ # cat /proc/cmdline root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 console=ttymxc2,115200 rootwait fixrtc consoleblank=0 lpj=7905280 video=mxcfb0:dev=hdmi,1366x768M@60,if=RGB24 fbmem=10M,28M vmalloc=400M uboot_version=01.00.00`

`/ # cat /sys/class/graphics/fb0/mode U:1280x720p-60`

What ever the resolution I try the -xres was being forced to 1280 on the monitor I am using. I verified that my monitor supports the resolutions till **1680x1050**.

I tried the below option:

`fbset -xres 1366 -yres 768 -match`

But, that made the screen to go blank and doing `cat` on `/sys/class/graphics/fb0/mode` showed nothing.

All the options am trying to change the resolution were not working fine. Any help on this is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In u-boot set the boot args as:

```
setenv bootargs mxcfb0:dev=hdmi,1280x720M@60,if=RGB24
```

Replace `1280x720M` with what is needed to set the resolution as per your requirement.

Refer to [this website](https://boundarydevices.com/configuring-i-mx6-machines-different-screens-nitrogen6x-sabre-lite/), It will work.